# Why is Redline RPM setting super weird permissions?

Tags: java, rpm

Background: I'm using the [Redline Java library](http://redline-rpm.org/index.html) to build an rpm.

I'm trying to set a basic 774 permission for my file like so:

`builder.addFile(rpmFileName,new File(sourceName), 774, -1, defaultUser, defaultGroup)`

but this results in creating files with super weird permissions like d--x------T where even the default user can't so much as read the file.

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://redline-rpm.org/apidocs/index.html) for Builder says

> mode - the mode of the target file in standard three octet notation

but this doesn't mean you should enter the mode as you'd expect to read it with an 'll' command in Unix. Instead, you must give the input in **decimal** format or explicitly indicate that the entry is octal by putting a '0' in front. So to enter 774, you'll need to put 508 or 0774. To set permissions of 664, you'll need to put 436 or 0664.

Using a calculator in Programmer mode should make the conversion easy (enter desired value (774) as OCT and then read the DEC value (508))

Comment: That's messed up. Have you tried a leading `0` to tell it it is octal?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco leading 0 works. So you can either enter a decimal conversion of octal or directly enter octal.

Comment: There you go... lazy `scanf` parsing or something like that... ;)